# .NET Web App Change Color/Theme Day/Night Mode in User Settings?

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, colors, themes

I am building a new ASP .NET web application using MVC and Angular for the front end. Right now I am dealing with designing the front-end framework/ground work for the future of this application.

I would like to allow the user to go to their settings to change their UI theme from a day mode to a night mode (and maybe a couple other themes if we decide). Basically all this should do is change the colors that the applications uses.

In order to achieve this, I would like to implement some sort of color variables such as "primaryColor", "secondaryColor", "errorColor", etc... This would make it very easy for us as developers to write new themes. All the CSS in the application in theory should reference these variables.

**Question: how should I go about adding theme/color-changing support for the front-end of my application? What are my options?**

*Potential Solutions I have been exploring: CSS, Materialize, Bootstrap, SASS, LESS.*

*CSS: My first hope was that CSS supported simple variables for things such as colors that can be changed at run-time, and maybe I just didn't know about them. It appears this is not a possibility?*

*Materialize: I really like the design. They even support SASS. But I cannot figure out a way to allow users to change their theme. It also seems like it would significantly slow down the site since it has to be pre-compiled on the server? In addition, if there is no way to alter the variables at run-time, why not just do a find-and-replace in the source file? It would allow us to do things such as specify the primary color however*

*Bootstrap: I don't love bootstraps styles (other than the colors) quite as much as Materialize, but it appears they support Bootswatch for certain Bootstrap themes? But it seems like this would be much more complicated than editing the primary and secondary colors since we would like to implement our own colors.*

*SASS/LESS: Materialize + SASS. If not, then maybe we could use sass/less to manually create our own?*

edit: I have also been researching Angular Material, but there seems to be a lack of documentation for how to add it into a .net application

Comment: Can you clarify if you want users to be able to specify specific colors? Or do you just want users to choose from a pre-created set of themes? If the latter, it seems like you could just toggle which color-theme CSS file was loaded based on user setting. I wouldn't see a need for C# color variables.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Users would not be able to choose colors. Me and the other devs would add in the colors to a pre-created list of themes. And I wouldn't want to do anything with color variables in C#. What is the color-theme CSS file? How do I add/reference/code it?

Comment: Setting aside anything fancy (SASS, LESS, bootstrap, etc), you could have a master CSS file that has all of your default styles. Then you could have theme files that extend/override the master file for each user-selectable theme. In the app, then, you could serve up whichever theme CSS file the user has selected. I can't speak to exact implementation without knowing your app architecture, but it should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: This is a new application, so we have the ability to set it up pretty much any way we want to